# How do I configure Doxygen to generate docs for only one file?

Tags: java, doxygen

I want to generate docs for a single Java class of a very large project. How do I do that? I'm pretty sure I did it a few years back. It has a lot of dependencies so I can't just copy the class to another directory.

I can use the command line or the OS X Doxywizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use doxygen to generate documentation from just one file , say `aa.java` one can use a normal doxygen configuration file and set in it:

```
INPUT = aa.java
```

depending on what is all present in the file `aa.java` it might that you have to use

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS =
```

as well

See (with excerpts from the doxygen manual, http://doxygen.nl/manual):

- INPUT: http://doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input

  > The INPUT tag is used to specify the files and/or directories that contain documented source files. You may enter file names like myfile.cpp or directories like /usr/src/myproject.
- EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS: http://doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_exclude_symbols

  > The EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS tag can be used to specify one or more symbol names (namespaces, classes, functions, etc.) that should be excluded from the output. The symbol name can be a fully qualified name, a word, or if the wildcard * is used, a substring. Examples: ANamespace, AClass, AClass::ANamespace, ANamespace::*Test